# How to insert a text between two cases in a multi valued function?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, cases

I want to do something similar to this but do not know how:

[image: Multi valued function]

I do know how to write multi-valued functions by using cases or align or whatever but do not know how to achieve a text that is to the right and in the MIDDLE between two cases.

How can this be done?

Comment: If your write `\[ \begin{cases} … \end{cases} \; k > \frac{B}{2}; \]` you get what you want. But may be it's not the optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Although `amsmath` provides a `cases` environment, this isn’t a case for `cases`. The construct contains two (sub-)formulas. The `aligned` environment can be used here. The left brace `\{` scales correctly with the height of the `aligned` environment when used with `\left` which needs a final `\right.`.

I also took the liberty to use `mathtools`’ `\mathclap` to not create horizontal gaps around the `\sum` signs.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
 \left\{
 \begin{aligned}
   x_{k+l} &= x_k - y_k \sum_{i=k}^{\mathclap{k+l-1}} r_i 2^{-i}, \\
   y_{k+l} &= y_k - x_k \sum_{i=k}^{\mathclap{k+l-1}} r_i 2^{-i}, \\
 \end{aligned}
 \right.
 k > \frac{B}{2};
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Colab MathJax does not understand `\left\{`. Use can use `\bigg\{` instead.